# Should block titles be <h2>?

Tags: theming

These `<h2>` heading tags, in the canonical sense, should be used as headings only, right?

In Drupal, it seems these block headings get `<h2>` tags, but they aren't semantic headings insofar as being legitimate paragraph headings on legitimate paragraphs.

Surely as a search spider would not readily distinguish these tags, they in fact not be `<h2>` but standard `<div>`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'heading' != 'paragraph heading' (in fact there's no such thing as an HTML paragraph heading). A heading tag is used to denote the heading of a section (a conceptual section, not necessarily a `<section />` tag) - it doesn't have to be above, or any where near, a paragraph.

If you're interested in SEO, whatever you do don't convert them from an `<h2>` to a `<div>`. A `<div>` carries no semantic weighting whatsoever, while an `<h2>` does. If you're not happy with `<h2>`, obviously choose something else, but for the love of Matt Cutts not a `<div>` :)

Personally the only tags I'd recommend are `<h2>` (which is standard for adding a heading to a section in any website, not just a Drupal one) or `<h3>`, if you're already using `<h2>`'s to markup more semantically important sections elsewhere in the page.

Comment: What do you make of this code block then, also from Drupal:

<h1 id="logo">
<a href="/" rel="home">
<img src="logo.png" alt="WikiJob logo" title="Home page">
</a>
</h1>

Comment: I agree.  I think using <h2> to denote the heading of a block *is* actually close to the semantic meaning of what an <h2> should denote both to a spider and to a human and visually.

Comment: @cjm2671 Sorry not really sure what you mean - that's the `<h1>` tag, there's one of those per page in any (correct) theme. It's not related to the `<h2>` tags in any way

Comment: I agree, just wanted to check.

Answer (score 0):

Every taxonomy page has a list of H2, linking to the articles listed on the page. I'd assume 10 H2s on a page could hurt your SEO. And if you add a few blocks on the page, everything gets even more confusing. I'm using H3 for taxonomy pages and H2 for block titles. Everything else should be H3, although H3 weighs so much less.